# is AngularJS unique filter from AngularUI deprecated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use the unique filter in the ngOptions part of a select, but I get this error `Unknown provider: uniqueFilterProvider <- uniqueFilter`  I read various questions and I know that I need to add that module to my App, but I think that they are outdated since all the links go to this pages http://angular-ui.github.io/#modules and this one https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js

I could use the second link but I prefer to use a newer version since the link says OLD-REPO, what is the newer version of this function in Angular UI or is implemented in AngularJS

I'm using `angularJS-1.4.8`

Comment: Not answering the question, but you should check [this repo](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#unique). There a a lot of awesome filters.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `ngLodash` library, which has various methods of filtering/sorting arrays and objects. See [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs)

Check out the `_.uniq()` method.

You can use this method to prefilter your list of options, then use the filtered list in your `ng-options`